# Java Applet needs to read MySQL

Tags: mysql, applet

I have a Java Applet hosted online which is merrily reading data from CSV files.

However my host has MySQL and I'd like to start read/writing a database instead.

I'm happily accessing MySQL on my home PC with Java (NOT an Applet) via JConnector.

For starters the jar file *mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar* needs uploading to my web server right?

When running my own database-accessing programs from NetBeans I added this jar file to the Netbeans project "Libraries". When compiling/running from command prompt I used "-classpath".

However, an Applet runs on an html page not Netbeans nor DOS! Therefore: by what mechanism do we convey the location of the Driver .jar file to the Applet?

Many thanks, Robin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An applet should not be directly accessing the DB.  Instead it should be forced to go through server-side functionality (JSP, servlet, ASP etc.) that mediates what it can & cannot do.

For either the applet or the server-side mediated solution, the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar` will need to be on the run-time class-path.  For a servlet/JSP, that would be by putting it into (from memory) `WEB-INF/lib`.  For an applet, added to the `archive` attribute of the `applet` element.

Comment: Thank you Sir. I will need to do some digging now because some of what you mention is new to me. But at least I'm not 'stuck' any more, so thank you for your time.